# How to write a TypeScript function that takes an object and only requires a single property?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to break my bad habit of using `any` in my TypeScript code. I'm having a hard time correctly writing a function where I pass in an array and a single item, and it either adds that item or removes it from the array.

I really don't care what the shape of the item is. The only requirement is that it has an `id` property of type `string`. Below is the only way I know how to write this:

```js
interface Item {
  id: string;
  [key: string]: any;
}

function toggleArrayItem(array: Item[], item: Item) {
  const index = array.findIndex(i => i.id === item.id);

  if (index >= 0) {
    array.splice(index, 1);
  } else {
    array.push(item);
  }
}
```

The only thing I can think of is changing that 3rd line to:

```js
  [key: string]: string | number | string[] | number[] | /* ad nauseum */
```

but that's not going to work for obvious reasons. What's the proper way to write this function so I don't have to rely on `any` as a crutch?

Comment: Have you thought about generics? You could remove the indexer and just keep the id on the interface and define the function as `function toggleArrayItem<T extends Item>(array: T[]) {...}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do the job:

```ts
interface Item {
  id: string;
}

function toggleArrayItem<T extends Item>(array: T[], item: T){
  const index = array.findIndex((i) => i.id === item.id);

  if (index >= 0) {
    array.splice(index, 1);
  } else {
    array.push(item);
  }
}

const i =  {id: '123', name: 'something'};
const j =  {id: '1234', age: 123};
const k =  {id: '12341', age: 11};

toggleArrayItem([] as Item[], i);
toggleArrayItem([j,k], j);
```

Check this out at TS Playground: https://tsplay.dev/wRpQvm

Comment: Interesting, so even though the function accepts a generic, it's not required when you call the function?

Comment: @ffxsam as in, require to be specified within `<T>`? Typescript infers the generic. Specifying manually is only used when you want to override that infer.

Comment: @Chase Follow-up note: Holy smokes. How have I not understood generics this whole time?? I was under the false impression that if you specified a generic, it was then required to specify one when calling the func, e.g. `toggleArrayItem<Thing>(..., ...)`. I need to revisit the TS Handbook.

Comment: @ffxsam Generics are super cool, and really powerful :)

Comment: @ffxsam late to the party... when I started picking up TypeScript (I was a Java guy), although the Handbook documentation is powerful, I found that GitHub tickets have much better discussions on why something works and why something not... specially, cliff notes by Ryan Cavanaugh turned out to be exceptionally educational. HTH

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `[key: string]: any;` if you don't need it:

```js
interface Item {
  id: string;
}

function toggleArrayItem(array: Item[], item: Item) {
  const index = array.findIndex(i => i.id === item.id);

  if (index >= 0) {
    array.splice(index, 1);
  } else {
    array.push(item);
  }
}
```